# Data duplication of API in the .vue file in NUXT3

Tags: javascript, duplicates, vuejs3, nuxt3

I have snippet of code in my .vue file:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
// get data from Data base

const nodePositions = await useApi('get_dictionary_info', 'GET', { name: 'node_positions' })
const providers = await useApi('get_dictionary_info', 'GET', { name: 'providers' })
```

`useApi` is the function, that fetches from the API:

```
export async function useApi<T extends Endpoint>(path: Ref<T> | T, method: RequestType, params?: Ref<APIParams<T>> | APIParams<T>, options?: AsyncDataOptions<Array<APIOutput<Partial<T>>>>) {
      return await useAsyncData(
        `${method}_${typeof path === 'object' ? path.value : path}`,
        () => $fetch<Array<APIOutput<Partial<T>>>>(`/api/${typeof path === 'object' ? path.value : path}`, { method, [method === 'GET' || method === 'DELETE' ? 'query' : 'body']: ('value' in params! ? params?.value : params) }),
        options
      )
    }
```

Code of API (location ./server/api/get_dictionary_info.ts):

```
import prisma from '~/prisma/instance'
import Joi from 'joi'
import { Dictionaries, DictionaryInput } from '~/types'

type QueryArgs = { name: Dictionaries }
type KeyTypes = {
  [Key in Dictionaries]: string | { t: string, k: string[] }
}
type Result = Promise<Array<Omit<DictionaryInput, 'created_at'>> | undefined>

export default defineEventHandler(async (event): Result => {
  if (event.node.req.method === 'GET') {
    const options = getNormalizedQuery(event) as QueryArgs

    const tables: KeyTypes = {
      assignments: 'objectAssignment',
      subdivisions: 'objectSubdivision',
      object_types: 'objectType',
      node_positions: 'nodePosition',
      providers: { t: 'provider', k: ['id', 'name', 'short_name'] }
    }

    validate(options, {
      name: Joi.string().valid(...Object.keys(tables)).required()
    })

    const tableType = typeof tables[options.name] === 'string' ? tables[options.name] : (tables[options.name] as { t: string }).t
    const select = typeof tables[options.name] === 'string'
      ? { id: true, name: true, description: true }
      : Object.fromEntries((tables[options.name] as { k: string[] }).k.map(x => [ x, true ]))

    // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/ban-ts-comment
    // @ts-ignore
    return await prisma?.[tableType].findMany({ select })
  }
  else {
    throw createError({
      statusCode: 403
    })
  }
})
```

It was supposed that if I use the API with different values of key 'name', then I get the corresponding arrays from the database, but it turns out that the result of the second use of the API is overwritten in the first variable. As a result, the same array is written to two different variables. How can I get different arrays in two variables?

Comment: I've already resolved this issue. I've used 'Unstorage' library: https://unstorage.unjs.io